# PHP get 4 characters before position

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the 'GMT ' (just an example for better understanding, the goal is to get vcard ID) word from a string where it shows multiple times

```
$vcards = 'cc4f9b7b-3cd6-4335-9e5a-254c60c56731 82e45a0303680f0b787f5352d7486310 Wed, 19 Apr 2017 18:10:10 GMT BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 REV:2017-04-19T19:10:12Z N;CHARSET=utf-8:cc4f9b7b-3cd6-4335-9e5a-254c60c56731 82e45a0303680f0b787f5352d7486310 Wed, 19 Apr 2017 18:10:10 GMT BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 REV:2017-04-19T19:10:12Z N;CHARSET=utf-8:';

$filterword = 'BEGIN:VCARD';

preg_match_all('/\bBEGIN:VCARD\b/', $vcards, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
//print_r($m);

$count = count($m[0]);
$count = $count - 1;
//echo $count;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $offset = $m[0][$i][1];
    echo substr($vcards, $offset, $offset);
}
```

Goal is to get GMT two times only but I've been only able to get random results that do not matter, I've left one of the attemps I've been doing.

The `$m[0][$i][1]` is the position where the words appears.

Comment: Show exactly what you want as a result.

Comment: The echo should be `'GMT GMT '` as it shows two times before the two times `'BEGIN:VCARD'` appears

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a more complex Regx  something like

```
  [a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sGMT\sBEGIN:VCARD
```

You can try it here
https://regex101.com/r/FTOPXW/1

As it's kind of vague what you want, it shouldn't be to hard to work back from that.

Comment: I was able to do it on the link and it works ok and as expected. But I get an error in PHP with this `preg_match_all('[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}\s[a-z0-9]{32}\s[a-z]{3},\s\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sGMT\sBEGIN:VCARD', $vcards, $matches);` error being: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '{'`

Comment: Your missing the opening and closing delimiters (typically `/` )such as  `preg_match_all('/[....]/')`  in your comment above it is using `[` as that delimiter which will mess everything up